# Stop Motion Video creation using external camera

Tags: camera, usb-on-the-go

my son is very interested in Lego stop-motion video creation.  There are myriad apps for stop motion capture on the Android platform, but using a device's internal camera isn't too easy, since you can't get a big phone or tablet into the correct position for the desired shots.

I have a USB webcam and a USB OTG cable.  Is there any way to use the external webcam as the image source for any of these stop-motion apps?

The idea setup would be to make the USB camera the *default* image source for any existing app.  Then he could directly capture into a simple, easy-to-use stop motion app instead of taking pictures first and inserting them frame-by-frame into the app later.

I have the following Android devices available, which can be used for this purpose:

- Galaxy S2 (Sprint) android 4.x?
- Galaxy S2 (AT&T) android 2.2
- Alcatel onetouch Fierce XL - android 5.5
- Samsung Galaxy Tab 10.1 - android 4.x?

I have a generic USB webcam, but I may be willing to purchase a specific external camera if this would ensure smooth functionality.

I'd appreciate any advice!

Comment: I'm in the same situation with my son today. Did you find a solution? Thanks XP

Comment: @xavier unfortunately no.